# Ros :problem in sourcing setup.bash during installation of ros melodic on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros

```
$ echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

OUTPUT => bash: /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Comment: also used  printenv | grep ROS
to set environment variables

Comment: Could you explain more what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried to search for the answer on [answers.ros.org](https://answers.ros.org)? [Here (link)](https://answers.ros.org/question/329877/i-have-followed-all-the-command-to-install-ros-melodic-in-ubuntu-bionic-but-stucked-at-setting-up-environment-variables/) is something what looks similar to your problem

Comment: @Ryan  i use source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.sh not setup.bash now i had installed ros melodic in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please add more detail.

Comment: @Ryan I there was no setup.bash file in the melodic because the setup file was named setup.sh and when I ran the command for "setup.sh" file then it worked.

Comment: @Ryan I was installing ros melodic and in the doc I had to source the setup.sh file but in doc of ros the file is named as setup.bash.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the ROS commands work,  you verify witch ros you have installed for that see `/opt/ros/DISTRO=?`

If you have installed ros correctly (you must to have the directory DISTRO= melodic or kinetics etc in /opt/ros/)

Then for melodic replace DISTRO by melodic in the following command and added it to `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source /opt/ros/DISTRO/setup.bash
```

Then

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
```

If you you have installed an other Ros like kinetic added the following command to `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetics/setup.bash
```

.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using Melodic?

try

```
$ echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

do you have "ros" catalog in /opt/?

Answer (score 0):

check ros distribution installed using this command

```
echo $ROS_DISTRO
```

for example if output is "melodic" then Add this line to .bashrc

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
```

You should also setup your workspace. For this go to your workspace, i. e. "catkin_ws" and make.

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

Now, Add this to your .bashrc for auto workspace setup.

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Now you are ready to go.